# How to disable add sheet button in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook I would like to disable the Add New Sheet button that is next to the tabs. I have searched and found the following that disable the insert options on the workbook book which is great.

```
Application.CommandBars("Ply").FindControl(, 945).Enabled = False 
Application.CommandBars("Insert").Controls(4).Enabled = False
```

But I have yet to find the command for the Add New Sheet button. Is there a place that lists all these options or a tool I can use to identify the control or button.

The workbook is shared so automatically deleting the sheet on creation will not work.

Protect Structure does not work either and throws the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you not protect the structure of the workbook?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Unfortunately not the workbook forces the use of macros and hides sheets and unhides others based upon what the user does and it throws an error when protect for structure is enabled.

Comment: You have not given us many choices :D Well, in that case hide the sheet tabs and use navigators to jump from sheet to sheet? This way they cannot use the "+" sign to add the sheet?

Comment: Well I would like the sheet tabs to stay if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a proper solution to your actual problem, but it will give the illusion of doing what you want...

In the ThisWorkbook module, add this to instantly hide any new sheets with 'DeleteThisSheet' in cell A1

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

Sh.Cells(1, 1) = "DeleteThisSheet"
Sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Obviously, this will clutter up the workbook with hidden sheets, so you can clear them out from time to time using this code to switch off sharing and delete the hidden sheets.

```
Sub removeSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

' Turn off sharing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
End If

' Delete veryhidden sheets with delete code
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden And ws.Cells(1, 1) = "DeleteThisSheet" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

' Turn sharing back on
If Not ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Name, accessmode:=xlShared
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

As I say, it's not ideal, but may at least serve your purpose, although probably won't stand up to many people repeatedly attempting to add new sheets. You could possibly add a msgbox to the newssheet code to say something along the lines of 'This action has been disabled' to stop them retrying. I'll keep an eye on this thread to see if anyone comes up with a proper solution, it's always good to learn something new.

Comment: Dave I ended up doing something similar to this and instituted a weekly automated maintenance on the workbooks that unshares the file and removes all the extra sheets as well as does a bunch of other house cleaning. I didn't end up hiding the sheets but it does the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

In the **ThisWorkbook** code sheet, paste the following.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sh.Delete
End Sub
```

Any new (or copied) worksheet that is created is instantly deleted.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the workbook is shared so the answer you supplied will not work. I have added this info to the original question.

Comment: I don't really see how this is a reason for this answer not working properly. Could you explain?

Comment: You are not able to delete a sheet from a shared workbook excel does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the issue:

```
Application.CommandBars("Insert").Controls(4).Visible = False
```

This uses Visible property.